# When I try to move the folder, the copying process begins

Tags: external-disk, filesystem, folders, copy-paste

Why, when I move (using mouse) one folder into another, instead of moving, copying process starts? How to fix it?

OS X El Capitan
Folders are located on an external drive, GUID partition scheme, connected via USB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold the  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  key as you drag.
This will reverse the default behaviour of 'move to same drive, copy to another'

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped! Why this problem occurs when I move some folders, and does not happen with others? Is it possible to somehow set up this default behaviour  for all of them?

Comment: It should only try to copy if you are moving data between partitions. If it is to the same partition it will move. There is no way I know of to change that behaviour [which is a very sensible default]

Comment: I see ... it's strange, because these folders are located on the same drive, they may still be in different partitions?

Comment: possibly - you'd have to look at the partition map in Disk Utility to know for certain